# Loading XML file using as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

```
public class loadXML extends Sprite
{
    public var xmlFileName:String;
    public var urlL:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    public var urlR:URLRequest;
    public var xml:XML = new XML();

    public function loadXML(xmlS:String):void
    {
        xmlFileName = xmlS;
        urlR =  new URLRequest(xmlFileName);            
        urlL.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressAction);
        urlL.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedAction);
        urlL.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorAction);
        urlL.load(urlR);            
    }
    public function onLoadedAction(e:Event):void
    {
        xml = XML(e.target.data);
        //trace(xml);
    }       
    public function onProgressAction(e:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        //trace("loading xml");
    }
    public function errorAction(e:IOError):void
    {
        trace(e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

//main class

```
package
{
import com.loadXML;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class xmlFileView extends Sprite
{
    public var xmlData:loadXML;
    public function xmlFileView():void
    {
        init();
    }
    private function init():void
    {
        xmlData = new loadXML("list.xml");
        var xmlF:XML = XML(xmlData);
        //trace(xmlF.video[0].path);

    }
}
```

}

Here I instantiate the loadXML class. But I can't able to access the xml, y? and how can I achieve that?

here is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<videos>
    <video>
        <path>video1.flv</path>
    </video>
    <video>
        <path>video2.flv</path>
    </video>
    <video>
        <path>video3.flv</path>
    </video>
    <video>
        <path>video4.flv</path>
    </video>
</videos>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the xml you have there is looking not like xml :)
here how it should look like reffering the `trace(xmlF.video.path[0]);`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <video>
        <path>video1.flv</path>
        <path>video2.flv</path>
        <path>video3.flv</path>
        <path>video4.flv</path>
    </video>
</data>
```

**UPDATE**

you can not do like this:

```
xmlData = new loadXML("list.xml");
var xmlF:XML = XML(xmlData);
```

because loading something takes time, and script is not waiting until the loading has been done.

If you want to achive this you need to do it following way:
in the loadXML class edit function:

```
public function onLoadedAction(e:Event):void
{
    xml = XML(e.target.data);
    // dispatch event when the XML has been loaded and xml value is defined.
    dispatchEvent ( new Event ( Event.COMPLETE ) )
}
```

in the xmlFileView class edit:

```
private function init():void
{
    xmlData = new loadXML("list.xml");
    // listen for loading completed
    xmlData.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE, handleXMLLoaded );
}

private function handleXMLLoaded (e:Event):void
{
   var xmlF:XML = xmlData.xml
   trace(xmlF.video.path[0]); 
}
```

Comment: eddited the answer, hope it will help.

Comment: @Jevgenij Dmitrijev `private function handleXMLLoaded (e:Event):void {}`*

Comment: kooooooo..... great thanks to Jevgenij Dmitrijev.

Can u explain, what is the roll of "dispatcherEvent"?

Comment: check these links to understand more about eventlisteners: http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2009/02/06/using-as3-event-listeners/ , http://jeffnehlsen.com/2011/02/actionscript-3-custom-events-explained/